# Alternative for "$(document).ready" function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox, document-ready

I am using fancybox in an aspx page. The document ready function does not work in this page for a lightbox. Someone told me to write a new javascript code for loading the lightbox in that page.

Comment: If you want to execute your script when everything is loaded use  `$(window).load(function(){ // ...})`

Comment: @undefined, this is almost the same as `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`. `load()` will wait until the graphics are also loaded.

Comment: Why is $(document).ready not working? You do have jQuery included right?

Comment: try jQuery.noConflict() method first.

Answer (score 49):

- Include jQuery.
- Check network tab that you are not getting 404.
- Check console that you are not getting "$ is unknown".

Do stuff when DOM is ready.

```
$(function(){
   // DOM Ready - do your stuff 
});
```

Comment: I think he means alternative to jquery load event

Comment: regardless of what the OP meant, I keep revisiting this page via Google (because I seem to forget this nifty convention). Thanks @user338195!

Answer (score 43):

Try this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   // ...
});
```

Works in modern browers and IE9+

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't work if the DOM has already loaded. If that's going to be a problem, take a look at these answers instead:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/799981

https://stackoverflow.com/q/9899372

Answer (score 7):

You could use the standard js onload function to run if that's what your'e missing:

```
window.onload = function() {};
```

Do note that this might give you issues with libraries - I haven't investigated that.

Answer (score 4):

I believe using the script `defer` tag is the best solution. For example,

```
<script src="demo_defer.js" defer></script>
```

More information at [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp).

Comment: I actually didn't know about this and I kinda pride myself on knowing the common "unknowns" lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

best ways is to use like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
  $(function() {
   // by passing the $ you can code using the $ alias for jQuery
   alert('Page: ' + $('title').html() + ' dom loaded!');
  });
})(jQuery);
```